# Jquery change link inside iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code, on each click i want change the link inside the iframe tag.

```
<div id="video" class="video">
    <iframe width="1030" height="600"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
    </iframe>
 </div>



 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#sub-01').click(function(){
    $('iframe src').text('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQPlp-xT-Cc');
 });

});
```

Somebody can help me? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please, read about the difference between `.text()` and `.attr()` or `.prop()`. PS: You do realize that you have no #sub-01 element

Comment: To set the `src` attribute of the `iframe` you need to use `prop()` or `attr()`, not `text()`. Check the duplicate for an example. I'd also suggest reading the jQuery documentation.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#sub-01').click(function(){
     $('iframe').attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQPlp-xT-Cc");
 });

});